# Why does ImageView.setImageMatrix() not work?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to rotate an image using ImageView.setImageMatrix(matrix) but it simply doesn't have any effect.
I call matrix.postRotate(45, 20, 20); before passing it to the function above but no effect, the image is not rotated. Why?

```
matrix.postRotate(45, 20, 20);
ImageView.setImageMatrix(matrix)
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I'm not really sure but I think you should set scale type:

```
imgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
```

You can also do that in XML with `android:scaleType="matrix"`.

Comment: @Mr. Roland: oh good. I was not sure because recently I looked at ImageView source and found that `mMatrix` (the image matrix) is read also in other modes, but I looked again now and actually it is reset by using the `Matrix.set*()` series of methods.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. My code    `Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
     matrix.postRotate(90);
  my_img.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
     my_img.setImageMatrix(matrix);` and nothing happens!

Comment: You need to use `matrix.postRotate(90, imageWidth / 2, imageHeigth / 2);`

Comment: Setting the drawable AFTER setting the matrix fixed the issue for me

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck with this for a long time :)