# imageview.setImageMatrix does not change the image

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I am changing the image matrix (zooming and dragging) and calling  *imageview.setImageMatrix(matrix)*  but the image won't change.

I didn't forget to set:

> android:scaleType="matrix"

in the xml file.

I checked the Log and the touch events are intercepted correctly + the matrix itself is calculated correctly.

but still... no effect on the image on screen....

Did anyone encounter this strange behavior?

Comment: did you call `invalidate()` on your ImageView after changing the matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post might help you [Why does ImageView.setImageMatrix() not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776570/why-does-imageview-setimagematrix-not-work) 
and remember (from doc) *Matrix does not have a constructor, so it must be explicitly initialized using either reset() - to construct an identity matrix, or one of the set..() functions (e.g. setTranslate, setRotate, etc.).*

Comment: I find that documentation confusing.  While the header does state that there is no constructor, if you look further down Matrix does in fact have two constructors and the documentation for the zero-argument constructor states "Create an identity matrix" which would seem to be in direct conflict with the documentation in the header.

Comment: @ScottW Bug report: [Conflicting information on the page for Matrix](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=34552).